# Skip to the next iteration if a warning is raised

Tags: python

How can I skip the iteration if warning is raised

Suppose I have the code below

```
import warnings

# The function that might raise a warning
def my_func(x):
    if x % 2 != 0:
        warnings.warn("This is a warning")
        return "Problem"     
    else:
        return "No Problem"
        

for i in range(10):
    try:
        # code that may raise a warning
        k = my_func(i)
    except Warning:
        # skip to the next iteration if a warning is raised
        continue
        
    # rest of the code
    print(i, " : ",k) # Only print this if warning was not raised in try:except
```

I would expect this to print only even numbers as my_funct(i) will raise a warning for odd numbers

**update:**

`my_func(i)` was used just for illustration purposes, the actual problem I want to use might not have an obvious returned value that raises a warning.

Comment: You need to use [warning filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter) to turn warnings into exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warnings don't throw an exception by default.
You can specify warnings to throw an exception.
Just run this right after the import

```py
warnings.simplefilter("error")
```

Or, you can just check the result of the function. Check if the result was "Problem" or "No Problem".

```py
for i in range(10):
    k = my_func(i)
    if k == "Problem":
        continue
        
    # rest of the code
    print(i, " : ",k)
```

Comment: ``` my_func(i)``` was used just for illustration purposes, the actual problem I want to use might not have an obvious returned value that raises a warning.  think using  ```warnings.simplefilter("error")``` is the appropriate solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `warn` function throw a warning object that except will detect.

**CODE**:

```
import warnings

# The function that might raise a warning
def my_func(x):
    if x % 2 != 0:
        raise Warning('This is a warming')
    else:
        return "No Problem"
    

for i in range(10):
    try:
        # code that may raise a warning
        k = my_func(i)
    except Warning:
        continue
    print(i, " : ",k)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
0 : No Problem
2 : No Problem
4 : No Problem
6 : No Problem
8 : No Problem
```